# Does the value of 'out' get updated with each iteration of the for loop?

Tags: verilog, hardware

I wrote code to reverse the bits of a 100-bit vector:

```
module top_module( 
    input [99:0] in,
    output [99:0] out
);
integer i;
    reg [99:0] temp;
    always@(*) begin
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i=i+1) begin
            temp[i] <= in[99-i];
        end
    end
    assign out = temp;
endmodule
```

I have two questions:

1. Do the `assign` statement and the `always` block execute in parallel?
2. I know that an `assign` statement is continuously assigned (i.e. it changes every time the RHS changes). So, does the value of `out` keep changing during every iteration of the `for` loop? What I mean to ask is, is this how the flow goes (assume `in` = 1011100........010)

   ```
    1st iteration: temp[0] <= 1; // (temp = xxxx.....1)
    2nd iteration: temp[1] <= 0; // (temp = xxxx.....01)
    ...
    100th iteration: temp[99] <= 0; (temp = 010......0011101 which is 'in' but flipped)
   ```

So, if 'out' is continuously assigned, does 'out' go through all 100 different values of `temp` until the loop ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `assign` statement and the `always` block execute in parallel in the sense that they execute at the same time step in simulation.  For example, if `in` changes value at time 5ns, then `out` will also be updated at time 5ns.

The `always` block triggers (executes) when `in` changes value.  The 1st iteration of the `for` loop sets `temp[0]` to 1.  If this changes `temp[0]`, then `out` is updated with the new value of `temp`.  The same happens on the 2nd iteration, and so on.  This means that `out` changes every time any bit of `temp` changes.

---

You could simplify the code by removing `temp` and just assigning `out` directly in the `for` loop:

```
module top_module( 
    input [99:0] in,
    output reg [99:0] out
);
integer i;
    always@(*) begin
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i=i+1) begin
            out[i] = in[99-i];
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Regardless, it is good practice to use a blocking assignment (`=`) inside the `always @(*)` block construct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `assign` and `always` constructs (as well as `initial`) each create a parallel/concurrent process.

The continuous `assign` statement is behaviorally equivalent to

```
alway @*
   out = temp;
```

except that Verilog does not allow procedural assignments to wires/nets. Unlike a variable, no value gets stored in a net.

Since you used a non-blocking assignment to make assignments to `temp` inside the `for` loop, the `for` loop completes 100 iterations before any change to `temp` happens. The changes are scheduled in the NBA region and then the assign statement will see one change to temp, assuming `in` has changed its value.

But if you used a blocking assignment (which you should have for combinational logic) the LRM does not guarantee whether all iteration would complete before executing the `assign` statement. The simulation is free to switch between processes at any point.

But most likely, the continuous assignment statement will be optimized away as just a name change, producing no executable code, not synthesizable logic.